# GNU assembly on bare metal for ARMv8 Foundation Model

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, bare-metal, fast-model

ARM released the ARMv8 emulation platform Foundation Model. I set up the environment according to the [guideline on linaro website](http://www.linaro.org/engineering/armv8/#tab1). 
It can support bare metal emulation because I tried example hello.axf binary file with

```
$ ./Foundation_v8pkg/Foundation_v8 --image ./Foundation_v8pkg/example/hello.axf
terminal_0: Listening for serial connection on port 5000
terminal_1: Listening for serial connection on port 5001
terminal_2: Listening for serial connection on port 5002
terminal_3: Listening for serial connection on port 5003
Simulation is started
Hello, 64-bit world!
$
```

It exited normally to command line prompt. I want to write a minimum assembly program which can run on bare metal, but I don't know how to. So I disassembly the hello.axf using [linaro armv8 toolchain](http://www.linaro.org/engineering/armv8/#tab3) for finding some clues:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -S hello.axf
```

and get the exit subroutine:

```
1663 00000000800017c8 <_sys_exit>:
1664     800017c8:   d10043ff        sub     sp, sp, #0x10
1665     800017cc:   d28004c1        movz    x1, #0x26
1666     800017d0:   f2a00041        movk    x1, #0x2, lsl #16
1667     800017d4:   f90003e1        str     x1, [sp]
1668     800017d8:   93407c00        sxtw    x0, w0
1669     800017dc:   f90007e0        str     x0, [sp,#8]
1670     800017e0:   910003e1        mov     x1, sp
1671     800017e4:   52800300        movz    w0, #0x18
1672     800017e8:   d45e0000        hlt     #0xf000
1673     800017ec:   14000000        b       800017ec <_sys_exit+0x24>
```

I write an assembly file test.s which only includes exit snippet:

```
.section .text, "ax"
.global _start
_start:
sub     sp, sp, #0x10                                                                                                  
movz    x1, #0x26
movk    x1, #0x2, lsl #16
str     x1, [sp]
sxtw    x0, w0
str     x0, [sp,#8]
mov     x1, sp
movz    w0, #0x18
hlt     #0xf000
b       .
```

And build it with:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-as test.s -o a.out
aarch64-linux-gnu-ld -Ttext=0x80000000 a.out -o test
```

Run it with:

```
$ ./Foundation_v8pkg/Foundation_v8 --image test
terminal_0: Listening for serial connection on port 5000
terminal_1: Listening for serial connection on port 5001
terminal_2: Listening for serial connection on port 5002
terminal_3: Listening for serial connection on port 5003
Simulation is started
```

The emulator is running, but it cannot normally exit to command line like the hello.axf example above. Sorry for the verbose description. My question is how I can write a minimum bare metal assembly program on ARMv8 Foundation Model.

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe you don't have the stack set up yet so writing may cause some unhandled exception that locks up the simulation. I am guessing that the important part in there is the `hlt`, so maybe try with only the last two instructions? (the `b .` is there only in case the `hlt` returns).

Comment: @Jester: I can confirm your suggestion works - submit it as an answer.

Comment: @unixsmurf I downloaded the linaro bare metal cross tool chain from https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries/+download And tried Jester's way. The simulator cannot exit neither.

Comment: @wm8120: ah, sorry, I mentally filtered away the branch to self - so to be correct, the last 3 instructions, starting with movz w0, #0x18.

Comment: @unixsmurf thx. It works. What I do is writing a linker script to layout the text section on address 0x00010000 and run the armv8 simulator with --secure-memory option.